# Subscribing to multiple observable<boolean> in a foreach loop?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a component with a query list of child components. Each of those child components exposes two methods, one that returns whether a form is valid as an `observable<boolean>`, and another that returns an object.

In the parent component, I want to loop through the child components and check that each child is valid. I have code like this

```
    let valid: boolean = true;
    children.forEach(r => {
       r.validate().subscribe(v => {
          if(!v){
             valid = v;
             }
          });    
       });
```

It then goes on to gather gather the objects if valid is still true after the foreach loop. However, I imagine this is not correct, as its possible that the foreach loop could finish before all the observables have emitted a value.I'm also unsure of the effect of assigning multiple subscriptions to the same variable.

Is there a better way of doing this, besides simply making the validate() method return a regular boolean? Would something like a forkjoin be better, where the foreach loop just forks all the observables together and emits a single array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

---

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

const allObs = forkJoin(...children.map(r => r.validate()));
allObs.subscribe(res => console.log(res)); // Do what you want with the array of results
```

Comment: Okay, great! This was my inclination as well, I was just unsure of its 'correctness'. While I have you ear, can I ask - do you typically use observables throughout the application in this way? I'm new to rxjs and angular in general, but the idea of a composable, asynchronous stream of data sounds very appealing, so that's what I'm aiming for, but it feels a bit messy at times.

Comment: @Qumbaala Using RxJS (and Observables in general) is definitely a good idea most of the time, especially when the main job of your app is to perform operations on data, pass that around, and repeat, all this in an async manner (which is usually the case for most apps). Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) excellent guide to reactive programming

Comment: The reason it can feel messy at the beginning is that it usually requires a shift of mindset, as RxJS is quite different from the way people are used to do things. You'll get used to it quickly

Comment: Thank you for your help! I use knockout about 45hrs a week, and while it does have the concept of computeds/observables, rxjs is a much more robust implementation of the idea. You're right though, the more I work with it the more I enjoy it. It seems their is an operator for every occasion. Thanks again!